# Avoid a ListBox to be scrollable

Tags: listbox, windows-phone-7

I have a ListBox so I can use bindings. I'm new to Silverlight so maybe there is another way. I just want to display a list of items in a template. I don't need it to be scollable, because it fits the screen. Here is ma code :

```
                <ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding NewSearchItems}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="440">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XAML:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
```

Comment: thanks ! I actually used VerticalScrollBarVisibility. As I said, i'm new, but it doesn't seem logic to me. I first thought it was only to set the visibility.

Comment: It's completely non-intuitive so don't sweat the fact that you didn't understand it's purpose.  I'd have saved a couple of hours myself if instead the property was named ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarEnabled and a boolean. ;)